# Compress Dynamic URL for QR Code

Tags: compression, qr-code, asp.net-web-api

I have a non-computing device that needs to send a user of that device to a certain web page based on the current state of the device. The state consists of multiple key-value pairs that we encode into a URL (e.g. `http://example.com/doMyStatus?prop1=val1&prop2=val2`). All told, this URL may reach 500+ characters so we cannot expect the user to type it into her browser manually.

Instead, we plan on displaying a QR code with the URL that a user can visit with a smartphone.
Due to this, we cannot submit this long URL as a POST request to the server (although that would be the best approach). Is there any way to compress a URL to fit within a medium-resolution QR code? We only need to compress the query string: the QR code will contain a URL like `http://example.com/decompress?compressedQueryString`.

Zip+Base64 just makes the URL longer. I've considered writing a custom URL shortener and having the device submit the URL for shortening before creating the QR code which is a lot more work (storing (short lived!) shortened URLs) but probably the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a URL shortner like http://yourls.org/ - it's self hosted, zero maintainence, and has a number of [plugins to autogenerate the QR codes](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/Plugin-List#q).

Answer (score 1):

I recently [created a scheme](http://blog.alivate.com.au/packed-url/) which achieves ~50% compression. [QR codes allow direct binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) so you don't need to have a final base64 encoding step.

Comment: That's a very useful solution, thanks. I had no idea QR codes allowed binary data too.